# Crash when assigning values to array

Tags: c++, arrays

This particular line of code is causing my program to crash. What is the reason?

```
square [b] = 'T';
```

where 'square' is a 1 dimensional character array with 64 elements, b is an integer.
It does not crash when I give a constant instead of b, for eg.,

```
square [5] = 'T';
```

EDIT:
@smilepleeaz the part causing the problem..

```
void traps()
{
    int a,b,r;
    cout<<"Deciding placement of traps";
    for (a = 1; a <= 8; a++)
    {
        r = clock();
        cout<<"\nPress any key\n";
        getch();
        cout<<"\nPress any key\n";
        getch();
        r = r - clock();
        b = r % 64;


        if (square [b] == '.')
        {
            square[b] = 'T';
        }
    }
    cout<<"\nTraps generated..... Press any key to continue\n";
    getch();
}
```

here is the entire code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>              //mainly to generate random numbers
#include <cstdlib>               // for clear screen
using namespace std;
int trap_hit = 0;              //0 => not stepped on trap
                               //1 => stepped on trap
char m;                //where the player wants to move
int player_position = 0;
//The game board "." denotes empty square
char square [64] {'O','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','X'};

//place traps
void traps()
{
    int a,b,r;
    cout<<"Deciding placement of traps";
    for (a = 1; a <= 8; a++)
    {
        r = clock();
        cout<<"\nPress any key\n";
        getch();
        cout<<"\nPress any key\n";
        getch();
        r = r - clock();
        b = r % 64;

        if (square [b] == '.')
        {
            square[b] = 'T';
            cout<<"Debug1";    //for debugging
        }
    }
    cout<<"\nTraps generated..... Press any key to continue\n";
    getch();
}

//to draw the board
void board()
{
    system ("cls");
    cout<<"           Dungeon crawl\n";
    cout<<"INSTRUCTIONS:use the keys \"w\", \"s\", \"a\" and \"d\"\n to move up, down, left and right respectively.\n Do not touch the Traps (T) or enemies (E)\n";
    cout<<"\n   "<<square [0]<<"   "<<square [1]<<"   "<<square [2]<<"   "<<square [3]<<"   "<<square [4]<<"   "<<square [5]<<"   "<<square [6]<<"   "<<square [7]<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n   "<<square [8]<<"   "<<square [9]<<"   "<<square [10]<<"   "<<square [11]<<"   "<<square [12]<<"   "<<square [13]<<"   "<<square [14]<<"   "<<square [15]<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n   "<<square [16]<<"   "<<square [17]<<"   "<<square [18]<<"   "<<square [19]<<"   "<<square [20]<<"   "<<square [21]<<"   "<<square [22]<<"   "<<square [23]<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n   "<<square [24]<<"   "<<square [25]<<"   "<<square [26]<<"   "<<square [27]<<"   "<<square [28]<<"   "<<square [29]<<"   "<<square [30]<<"   "<<square [31]<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n   "<<square [32]<<"   "<<square [33]<<"   "<<square [34]<<"   "<<square [35]<<"   "<<square [36]<<"   "<<square [37]<<"   "<<square [38]<<"   "<<square [39]<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n   "<<square [40]<<"   "<<square [41]<<"   "<<square [42]<<"   "<<square [43]<<"   "<<square [44]<<"   "<<square [45]<<"   "<<square [46]<<"   "<<square [47]<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n   "<<square [48]<<"   "<<square [49]<<"   "<<square [50]<<"   "<<square [51]<<"   "<<square [52]<<"   "<<square [53]<<"   "<<square [54]<<"   "<<square [55]<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n   "<<square [56]<<"   "<<square [57]<<"   "<<square [58]<<"   "<<square [59]<<"   "<<square [60]<<"   "<<square [61]<<"   "<<square [62]<<"   "<<square [63]<<"\n";

}

//allow user to move

void pl_move()
{
    char move_dir;
    invalid_move:
    cout<<"\nPress w, a, s or d ...... ";
    cin>>move_dir;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100000, '\n');
    //allow the player to move
    if (move_dir == 'w')
    {
        if (player_position < 8)               //trying to move out of the board
        {
            cout<<"Invalid move";
            goto invalid_move;
        }
        square [player_position] = '.';
        player_position = (player_position - 8);
        if (square [player_position] == 'T')
        {
            trap_hit = 1;
        }
        square [player_position] = 'O';
    }
    else if (move_dir == 's')
    {
        if (player_position >55 && player_position <64)                 //trying to move out of the board
        {
            cout<<"Invalid move";
            goto invalid_move;
        }
        square [player_position] = '.';
        player_position = (player_position + 8);
        if (square [player_position] == 'T')
        {
            trap_hit = 1;
        }
        square [player_position] = 'O';
    }
    else if (move_dir == 'a')
    {
        if ((player_position % 8) == 0)                     //trying to move out of the board
        {
            cout<<"Invalid move";
            goto invalid_move;
        }
        square [player_position] = '.';
        player_position = (player_position - 1);
        if (square [player_position] == 'T')
        {
            trap_hit = 1;
        }
        square [player_position] = 'O';
    }
    else if (move_dir == 'd')
    {
        if ((player_position % 8) == 7)                         //trying to move out of the board
        {
            cout<<"Invalid move";
            goto invalid_move;
        }
        square [player_position] = '.';
        player_position = (player_position + 1);
        if (square [player_position] == 'T')
        {
            trap_hit = 1;
        }
        square [player_position] = 'O';
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\nInvalid move";
        goto invalid_move;
    }
}



int main()
{
    traps();       

    while(trap_hit == 0 && player_position != 63)
    {
        board();
        pl_move();
    }
    board();
    if (trap_hit == 1)
    {
        cout<<"\nYou have stepped on a trap. You lose!";
    }
    else if (player_position == 63)
    {
        cout<<"\nYou have retrieved the treasure and won!";
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: whats the value of `b` that causing the crash ? Is it > 63 ?

Comment: @Bhaskar < 0 will trigger issues too :)

Comment: @AnthonySottile whatever, I've overseen this for a declaration, sorry.

Comment: Bhaskar, it can't be >63 or <0 since i am generating a random number and taking its remainder with 64.... something like
    b = r%64
b and r are integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for the validity of your array bounds and value of `b`.

`b` should obviously be:

**(Pseudo code):**

```
  MinBound <= b <= MaxBound
```

In your case , you can do as below:

```
void traps()
{
    int a,b,r;
    cout<<"Deciding placement of traps";
    for (a = 1; a <= 8; a++)
    {
        r = clock();
        cout<<"\nPress any key\n";
        getch();
        cout<<"\nPress any key\n";
        getch();
        cout<<"f1";  //debug
        r = clock() - r; //Edited to fix negetive values
        cout<<"f2";
        b = r % 64;
        cout<<"f3";

        //if (square [b] == '.')
        //{
        if(b < 0 || b>=64) //Validation Here
        continue;
            square[b] = 'T';
            cout<<"Debug1";
        //}
    }
    cout<<"\nTraps generated..... Press any key to continue\n";
    getch();
}
```

Comment: in C++ a way to check this would be `if (b < 0 || b >= array_size) { cout << "gtfo"; /* exit(1); ? */ }`

Comment: @AnthonySottile now can't one write a psuedo without getting downvoted? :(

Comment: It can't be >63 or <0 since i am generating a random number and taking its remainder with 64.... something like b = r%64 b and r are integers.

Comment: which part? I have pasted the entire program

Comment: The part containing logic and causing the problem. Pasted where?

Comment: Dont use clock() for random numbers, its giving -ve values and your b becomes negetive often causing problems. If you stil want to carry on with current approach see my edited answer for validation.

Comment: Thanks... Is there any other way to generate pseudorandom numbers? and how does clock give negative values? I thought clock() measured cpu time since start of program...

Comment: Actually this `r = r - clock();` is the culprit giving negetive values , obviously. You are substracting higher value from lower value. Edited my answer for fix.

Comment: You can use rand (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) for random numbers.

Comment: aargh!! didn't even notice that (higher from lower subtraction)... :( anyway, thanks..

Comment: Anytime :) You can mark my answer as solution if it solved your problem.

Comment: @smilepleeeaz Please use this reference [`rand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand), it's more up to date, and has less flaws than cplusplus.com.